# Unity Console error

Tags: c#, admob

I am using AdMob ad to my unity android game but during build process

**getting the following error:**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
E:\Android_SDK_Incide\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "E:/Android_SDK_Incide\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.google.android.gms:com.ultraaim.ballgame3d:android.support.v4:com.unity3d.ads.android -S "E:\Unity 4.3 training\FromUnity 5.0\3D Teeter Pro\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res" -S "E:\Unity 4.3 training\FromUnity 5.0\3D Teeter Pro\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res" -S "E:\Unity 4.3 training\FromUnity 5.0\3D Teeter Pro\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.1.1\res" -S "E:\Unity 4.3 training\FromUnity 5.0\3D Teeter Pro\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res"
```

and a lot more things below

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there could be problem with file duplicates. Check your project directory for duplicated *.jar's. Could you show the rest of errors?